# Why are some low CP pokemon hard to capture?

Tags: pokemon-go

Has anyone else had CP 60 Pidgeys and CP 40 Rattata (I'm level 17) evade capture?
Higher CP does not seem to *directly* correspond to capture chance, although it does.

Is there any rhyme or reason to which pokemon will resist capture and which will not? Or am I just seeing Jesus in the pancakes, and this is just seeing patterns where there are none?

Comment: Probably bad RNG!

Answer (score 4):

This has not been 100% confirmed but there have been many complaints that it gets harder to catch lower cp pokemon the higher trainer level you are. I personally have experienced this multiple times with low level weedles and caterpies.

> For instance, Riggnaros says, once you reach a level in the "mid 20s," low-powered Pokémon you encounter in the game start to "have an abnormally high chance to evade capture."
>   [Source](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2016/07/how-pokemon-go-starts-punishing-its-high-level-players/)

That's a quote taken from a person who had hit level 30 days ago.

There is definitely a direct correlation between high CP and difficulty of capture as pokemon with higher CP will have darker colored rings and evolved pokemon will also be harder to capture.

Source: Personal Experience

Comment: I don't see why people are downvoting you, you have a solid point and a source. But then again I noticed that a lot of questions tagged with Pokemon-Go are downvoted if they sound remotely off topic.

Comment: [Because Tim lost his keys again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397)

Answer (score 3):

All Pokemon have a Capture and Flee rate, there was a nice Google Spreadsheet page made with a list of all this data you can check it out [**here**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wZrKv5Y1cX7YInS0ztCHk1_gvrY4B27JVXm4mxoJYT8/edit#gid=1638340170).

It's happened to me a several times as well. A low CP Zubat immediately escaped after I failed one Pokeball throw. Some people say that if you travel too far away from where you have seen the Pokemon then the Pokemon will have a higher chance to escape.

Credits to this [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4t7qry/basic_pokemon_go_species_data_hpatkdef_catchflee/) for the Google Spreadsheet.